# Trying to calculate algorithm time complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

So last night I solved [this LeetCode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/solution/). My solution is not great, quite slow. So I'm trying to calculate the complexity of my algorithm to compare with standard algorithms that LeetCode lists in the Solution section. Here's my solution:

```py
class Solution:
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
        # Get lengths of all strings in the list and get the minimum
        # since common prefix can't be longer than the shortest string.
        # Catch ValueError if list is empty
        try:
            min_len = min(len(i) for i in strs)
        except ValueError:
            return ''

        # split strings into sets character-wise
        foo = [set(list(zip(*strs))[k]) for k in range(min_len)]

        # Now go through the resulting list and check whether resulting sets have length of 1
        # If true then add those characters to the prefix list. Break as soon as encounter
        # a set of length > 1.
        prefix = []
        for i in foo:
            if len(i) == 1:
                x, = i
                prefix.append(x)
            else:
                break
        common_prefix = ''.join(prefix)
        return common_prefix
```

I'm struggling a bit with calculating complexity. First step - getting minimum length of strings - takes O(n) where n is number of strings in the list. Then the last step is also easy - it should take O(m) where m is the length of the shortest string.

But the middle bit is confusing. `set(list(zip(*strs)))` should hopefully take O(m) again and then we do it n times so O(mn). But then overall complexity is O(mn + m + n) which seems way too low for how slow the solution is.

The other option is that the middle step is O(m^2*n), which makes a bit more sense. What is the proper way to calculate complexity here?

Comment: sidenote: I found that leetcode reported runtimes are likely affected by external factors.  So don't stress if your results look bad because it could just be a slow server.

Comment: Another thing is that scanning across the th character of many strings will have poor cache locality; that'll make the program run slower even though the complexity may be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the middle portion is `O{mn}`, as well the overall is `O{mn}` because that dwarfs the `O{m}` and `O{n}` terms for large values of `m` and `n`.

Your solution has an ideal order of runtime complexity.

### Optimize: Short-Circuit

However, you are probably dismayed that others have faster solutions.  I suspect that others likely short-circuit on the first non-matching index.

Let's consider a test case of 26 strings (`['a'*500, 'b'*500, 'c'*500, ...]`).  Your solution would proceed to create a list that is 500 long, with each entry containing a set of 26 elements.  Meanwhile, if you short-circuited, you would only process the first index, ie one set of 26 characters.

Try changing your `list` into a `generator`.  This might be all you need to short-circuit.

```
foo = (set(x) for x in zip(*strs)))
```

You can skip `min_len` check because default behaviour of `zip` is to iterate only as long as the shortest input.

### Optimize: Generating Intermediate Results

I see that you append each letter to a list, then `''.join(lst)`.  This is efficient, especially compared to the alternative of iteratively appending to a string.

However, we could just as easily save a counter `match_len`.  Then when we detect the first mis-match, just:

```
return strs[0][:match_len]
```

Comment: Creating a set from a list comprehension will still evaluate the whole set.

Comment: @sabik I pruned further my suggestion to `foo = (set(zip(*strs)))
`.  Will it work now?

Comment: That still constructs the set from the list comprehension. The outer brackets have no effect.

Comment: @sabik I agree that `set(zip(*strs))` will exhaust the `zip` iterator.  However, is it not the case that each `set` is constructed only after each `next(foo)`?  Please help me understand what I am missing.

Comment: `set(zip(*strs))` will exhaust the `zip` iterator and construct the whole set in memory.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean; `foo = (set(list(zip(*strs))[k]) for k in range(min_len))` would indeed construct it incrementally.

Comment: @sabik one `set` is created on each iteration of `foo`.  This set contains the `i`th digit.  Nary a single set is constructed until `next(foo)`.  Therefore, `foo = (set(zip(*strs)))` short-circuits.  I do not know why you linked the OP's code.  Could you respond to the code that I suggested?  Thanks

Comment: The code `foo = (set(zip(*strs)))` is equivalent to `foo = set(zip(*strs))` and immediately constructs the full set.

Comment: Thanks @sabik.  I didn't realize that you needed a `for` within the outer-most parentheses to actually turn the outer-most parentheses into a generator.  Have updated accordingly: `foo = (set(x) for x in zip(*strs)))`

Comment: @RazzleShazl Brilliant! With this small change the solution is suddenly faster than 94.1% of all other solutions and the runtime has dropped from around 60ms to 28ms!

Comment: @pavel That's music to my ears!